# How does taking out a group of observations bias your regression?

Tags: regression, bias, censoring

Assume you have a set of observations at time $t_1$ and you use it to estimate a regression $R1: y=b_0+b_1x$. The regression is used to predict the y-value for the future. You gather a set of (new) observations at time $t_2$. For this data, you are not able to observe the observations with a low *estimated* y-value anymore. For example, assume the case that getting data is expensive so you won't bother collecting those data, where you estimate y to be low (based on regression R1). However, for $t_3$ you still need to estimate a y-value for all observations and select which observations you spent money on to select.

How does that affect the predictions for $t_3$ that are made with the second regression $R2: y=b_0+b_1x$ that is based on the second, censored data?
I assume these are biased but are there any statistical results on the extent of the bias?

I am not expecting a full answer (though I'd be happy to hear it if you have it), but would enjoy getting some input or paths what I can look for. In general, I looked for censored regression models, but this case is a bit different as we only estimate the y-value to be lower, but cannot be sure. Is there anything in statistics I am not aware of that can describe this? Or there any  applications that this problem relates to? Anything that comes to your mind is helpful.

Comment: Is y only measured at t1?

Comment: Yes & no. Right now it is measured at all three time points, but I'd like to introduce what Frank below calls "context dependent sampling", then at t2 and t3 only special y-values are measured and I'd like to see how that affects the estimates that are based on this censored sample.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the more straightforward part of your question:

- the $t_3$ equation will bias upwards $b_0$
- $b_1$ should only be thought to generalize to those observations that survived through $t_2$
- The bias on $b_0$ will be proportional to the degree to which low $y$ was associated with not collecting the data

There are many possible approaches to your problem. Some of the things that matter are:

- whether you are collecting $y$ at both $t_1$ and $t_2$
- whether $x_1$ is the same observation at both times, or if they are observations of the same variable at different points in time, e.g. $x_t1$ and $x_t2$

Sometimes if you want to characterize something about the observations that drop out it is helpful to include an indicator variable (syntehtic 0s and 1s in a new column) to reflect whether the observation was collected. So long as you center (i.e. make your column for x equal to the mean of values of x), then you can often allow the indicator value to reflect information about the uncollected group. Be aware that depending on your usage and your data doing so can cause issues with homoscedasticity, the interpretation of your results, and your slope error estimates (and corresponding p-values).

Comment: For longitudinal analysis there is a specialty called outcome-dependent sampling that is worth searching.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments! Maybe to clarify: all observations are new observations with a different set of features. So the second point, the regression R2 will also be used to make predictions for those that would likely not make it through, basically to select which  observations to keep. These are basically decision made over time and after certain points in time, we want to determine which decision should be made in the future based on those in the past. I see we run into a sort of selection bias after t2. The comment on the outcome-dependent sampling is also very helpful!